# Getting the value of an onLongPressGesture duration

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I wanted to know how to get the duration of an LongPressGesture.

My goal is to be able to modify a variable proportionally to this LongGesture.

I tried to introduce a @State var in order to get the value via the .onChanged / .onEnded method but this one returns a boolean for the LongGesture

Here is my code (which does not compile) :

```swift
struct ContentView: View { 
    // Well, this var @State is a CGFloat because I think that the duration is of this type (based on the minimumDuration) 
   @State var timeLongGesture: CGFloat = 0
   @State var value: Int = 1
   var body: some View { 
   // Some stuff here
   Text("Increase the value") 
   .onTapGesture { value += 1 } 
   .gesture(
       LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.4)
           .onEnded { valueLongPress in
              // Here the error, because the value of "valueLongPress" is a Bool (as the doc mentionned)
              timeLongGesture = valueLongPress
            })
```

I feel like it's tricky. So if anyone has any ideas, I'll take it :-) 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would get the duration of an LongPressGesture:

```
class InitialTime: ObservableObject {
    @Published var initTime = Date()
}

struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var kickoff = InitialTime()

@State var timeLongGesture: Double = 0.0
@State var value: Int = 1
@GestureState var isDetectingLongPress = false

var body: some View {
    // Some stuff here
    Text("Increase the value")
        .onTapGesture { self.value += 1 }
        .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 3)
            .updating($isDetectingLongPress) { _, _, _ in
                self.kickoff.initTime = Date()
                print("--------> self.kickoff.initTime: \(self.kickoff.initTime)")
        }
        .onEnded { finished in
            self.timeLongGesture = Date().timeIntervalSince(self.kickoff.initTime)
            print("-----> timeLongGesture: \(self.timeLongGesture)")
        })
}
}
```